# Activating iPhone alarm and making sound

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

First post and first iPhone app in the making here, so please excuse the any n00b mistakes. I'm having trouble activating the alarm. I have a Datepicker and a button as the crux of the code. Here's the .h file

```
@interface Alarm : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate *alarm;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sleepButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timePicker;

- (IBAction)startAlarm:(id)sender;
- (void)checkAlarm;

@end
```

And here is the .m file.

```
- (IBAction)startAlarm:(id)sender
{
    self.alarm = [self.timePicker date];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(checkAlarm) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
{

- (void)checkAlarm
{
    // alarm is reached
    if ([NSDate date] == self.alarm)
    {
         // rest of code goes here
    }
{
```

I also have no idea how to make sound and make it repeat itself, so if I can get some guidance on how to do that, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this functionality built into the iOS clock app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if ([NSDate date] == self.alarm)
```

Dates have millisecond resolution, and your timer only fires once per second - the chances that they align perfectly is rather slim.

Instead you should check:

```
if ([[NSDate date] compare: self.alarm] == NSOrderedDescending)
```

to check if the alarm date was passed.